# In loopback Angular SDK, how to apply where filter on property of type object?

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

I have the following loopback model json file containing `content` property of type object:

```
{
"name": "ContentFeed",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "contentType": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "content": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

When creating, updating I'm saving data in the `value`, `formLink`, `formTitle` properties of this object. Can I filter on properties of object property?

I tried the following but it gave no result

```
ContentFeed
   .find({
      filter: {
         where: {
           "content.value": {regexp: $scope.searchText + '/i'}
        }
      }
    }).$promise
```